# MongoDb Timeseries Data at high Load Causes Cache Pressure in Time

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I'm encountering cache pressure issues in MongoDB, leading to early termination of buckets in my time series collections within a single database. Here's an overview of my system setup and the challenges I'm facing:

**MongoDB Version:** Community Edition 7.0.2

**System Configuration:** 128GB RAM, 12 CPUs, and 2TB SSD x3 (PSS).

**Data Ingestion Rate:** Approximately 120 million active socket data entries per day into time series collections.

**Time Series Collection Configuration:** Each collection uses deviceId as the metaField and has a granularity of minutes. Collections are created on a daily basis for the devices.

**PS:** Please Ignore the count of closedBuckets, I have realized after a while. That's why its so big in the first place.

**Issue Description:**

After beginning to save documents into the collections, I've observed that the on-disk size of my collections grows up to 3 times larger than normal in time(normal being 8GB and, in some cases, expanding to 24GB which is worst case with same amount of data). In an attempt to fine-tune the WiredTiger parameters to address this issue, I haven't yet succeeded.

Following the parameter adjustments, I restarted MongoDB, which cleared all WiredTiger caches, temporarily alleviating the cache pressure. However, this did not resolve the underlying problem, as numberOfBucketsClosedDueToCachePressure began to increase again within 4 days.

[image]

So Once this kicks into play, I have restarted the mongodb and All wiredtiger cache is deleted. So There was no longer cache pressure for a while(around 4 days) as I have configured the mongodb with these stats,

```
db.adminCommand( { "setParameter": 1, "wiredTigerEngineRuntimeConfig": "eviction=(threads_min=8,threads_max=16),checkpoint=(wait=60),eviction_dirty_trigger=10,eviction_dirty_target=5,eviction_trigger=95,eviction_target=80"})
```

And I also have increased **--WiredTigerCacheSizeGB** to 90GB rather than default.

But It didn't resolved my problem and **numberOfBucketsClosedDueToCachePressure** is started again after in 4 days, below,

[image]

And then I again restarted the Mongod. So Here is the metric I saved before the last restart,

```
db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache

{
  'application threads page read from disk to cache count': 152451515,
  'application threads page read from disk to cache time (usecs)': Long('8845187692'),
  'application threads page write from cache to disk count': 129757266,
  'application threads page write from cache to disk time (usecs)': Long('2717874335'),
  'bytes allocated for updates': 579813314,
  'bytes belonging to page images in the cache': Long('8548491672'),
  'bytes belonging to the history store table in the cache': 1237909068,
  'bytes currently in the cache': Long('9596083637'),
  'bytes dirty in the cache cumulative': Long('54447326651345'),
  'bytes not belonging to page images in the cache': 1047591964,
  'bytes read into cache': Long('23141148943904'),
  'bytes written from cache': Long('54251712735224'),
  'checkpoint blocked page eviction': 2215368,
  'checkpoint of history store file blocked non-history store page eviction': 0,
  'eviction calls to get a page': 530564173,
  'eviction calls to get a page found queue empty': 24519253,
  'eviction calls to get a page found queue empty after locking': 3357282,
  'eviction currently operating in aggressive mode': 0,
  'eviction empty score': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting a disk value without a timestamp behind the last update on the chain': 60,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting a tombstone without a timestamp ahead of the selected on disk update': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting a tombstone without a timestamp ahead of the selected on disk update after validating the update chain': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting update chain entries without timestamps after the selected on disk update': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to needing to remove a record from the history store but checkpoint is running': 0,
  'eviction passes of a file': 214853840,
  'eviction server candidate queue empty when topping up': 1069582,
  'eviction server candidate queue not empty when topping up': 19090331,
  'eviction server evicting pages': 0,
  'eviction server slept, because we did not make progress with eviction': 48373131,
  'eviction server unable to reach eviction goal': 0,
  'eviction server waiting for a leaf page': 5952,
  'eviction state': 32,
  'eviction walk most recent sleeps for checkpoint handle gathering': 10413,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 0-9': 168185695,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 10-31': 24765093,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 128 and higher': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 32-63': 6502801,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 64-128': 15400251,
  'eviction walk target pages reduced due to history store cache pressure': 0,
  'eviction walk target strategy both clean and dirty pages': 23101693,
  'eviction walk target strategy only clean pages': 1769786,
  'eviction walk target strategy only dirty pages': 189982361,
  'eviction walks abandoned': 3425789,
  'eviction walks gave up because they restarted their walk twice': 154422380,
  'eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found no candidates': 9295851,
  'eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found too few candidates': 769560,
  'eviction walks reached end of tree': 328742014,
  'eviction walks restarted': 0,
  'eviction walks started from root of tree': 166309038,
  'eviction walks started from saved location in tree': 48544802,
  'eviction worker thread active': 20,
  'eviction worker thread created': 13435,
  'eviction worker thread evicting pages': 501503267,
  'eviction worker thread removed': 13429,
  'eviction worker thread stable number': 14,
  'files with active eviction walks': 0,
  'files with new eviction walks started': 174319634,
  'force re-tuning of eviction workers once in a while': 7878,
  'forced eviction - do not retry count to evict pages selected to evict during reconciliation': 2721,
  'forced eviction - history store pages failed to evict while session has history store cursor open': 2652,
  'forced eviction - history store pages selected while session has history store cursor open': 14880,
  'forced eviction - history store pages successfully evicted while session has history store cursor open': 12228,
  'forced eviction - pages evicted that were clean count': 12261,
  'forced eviction - pages evicted that were clean time (usecs)': 30563,
  'forced eviction - pages evicted that were dirty count': 282910,
  'forced eviction - pages evicted that were dirty time (usecs)': 1108835767,
  'forced eviction - pages selected because of a large number of updates to a single item': 171045,
  'forced eviction - pages selected because of too many deleted items count': 88,
  'forced eviction - pages selected count': 5234782,
  'forced eviction - pages selected unable to be evicted count': 4939611,
  'forced eviction - pages selected unable to be evicted time': 75319296,
  'hazard pointer blocked page eviction': 3411193,
  'hazard pointer check calls': 507033786,
  'hazard pointer check entries walked': Long('6127148292'),
  'hazard pointer maximum array length': 2,
  'history store table insert calls': 751612906,
  'history store table insert calls that returned restart': 0,
  'history store table max on-disk size': 0,
  'history store table on-disk size': Long('22507274240'),
  'history store table reads': 1,
  'history store table reads missed': 0,
  'history store table reads requiring squashed modifies': 0,
  'history store table resolved updates without timestamps that lose their durable timestamp': 0,
  'history store table truncation by rollback to stable to remove an unstable update': 7275,
  'history store table truncation by rollback to stable to remove an update': 39,
  'history store table truncation to remove all the keys of a btree': 0,
  'history store table truncation to remove an update': 29,
  'history store table truncation to remove range of updates due to an update without a timestamp on data page': 0,
  'history store table truncation to remove range of updates due to key being removed from the data page during reconciliation': 0,
  'history store table truncations that would have happened in non-dryrun mode': 0,
  'history store table truncations to remove an unstable update that would have happened in non-dryrun mode': 0,
  'history store table truncations to remove an update that would have happened in non-dryrun mode': 0,
  'history store table updates without timestamps fixed up by reinserting with the fixed timestamp': 0,
  'history store table writes requiring squashed modifies': 8,
  'in-memory page passed criteria to be split': 634736,
  'in-memory page splits': 111872,
  'internal page split blocked its eviction': 145,
  'internal pages evicted': 62160564,
  'internal pages queued for eviction': 6516997,
  'internal pages seen by eviction walk': Long('3931843331'),
  'internal pages seen by eviction walk that are already queued': 2715118,
  'internal pages split during eviction': 2504,
  'leaf pages split during eviction': 115096679,
  'maximum bytes configured': Long('96636764160'),
  'maximum milliseconds spent at a single eviction': 41,
  'maximum page size seen at eviction': 10579040,
  'modified pages evicted': 285306123,
  'modified pages evicted by application threads': 2978,
  'operations timed out waiting for space in cache': 0,
  'overflow keys on a multiblock row-store page blocked its eviction': 0,
  'overflow pages read into cache': 0,
  'page split during eviction deepened the tree': 5,
  'page written requiring history store records': 140600952,
  'pages currently held in the cache': 183870,
  'pages evicted by application threads': 158968,
  'pages evicted in parallel with checkpoint': 214114332,
  'pages queued for eviction': 2015353761,
  'pages queued for eviction post lru sorting': 2015991125,
  'pages queued for urgent eviction': 96013667,
  'pages queued for urgent eviction during walk': 267220,
  'pages queued for urgent eviction from history store due to high dirty content': 0,
  'pages read into cache': 328889408,
  'pages read into cache after truncate': 0,
  'pages read into cache after truncate in prepare state': 0,
  'pages removed from the ordinary queue to be queued for urgent eviction': 3887,
  'pages requested from the cache': Long('19954273331'),
  'pages seen by eviction walk': Long('15722170027'),
  'pages seen by eviction walk that are already queued': 156099924,
  'pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted': 35366638,
  'pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted because of active children on an internal page': 184980,
  'pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted because of failure in reconciliation': 4569982,
  'pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted because of race between checkpoint and updates without timestamps': 0,
  'pages walked for eviction': Long('540580921486'),
  'pages written from cache': 677215717,
  'pages written requiring in-memory restoration': 128931795,
  'percentage overhead': 8,
  'recent modification of a page blocked its eviction': 0,
  'reverse splits performed': 34287,
  'reverse splits skipped because of VLCS namespace gap restrictions': 0,
  'the number of times full update inserted to history store': 417535460,
  'the number of times reverse modify inserted to history store': 334077349,
  'total milliseconds spent inside reentrant history store evictions in a reconciliation': 0,
  'tracked bytes belonging to internal pages in the cache': 570786066,
  'tracked bytes belonging to leaf pages in the cache': Long('9025297571'),
  'tracked dirty bytes in the cache': 1294875087,
  'tracked dirty pages in the cache': 11464,
  'uncommitted truncate blocked page eviction': 0,  'unmodified pages evicted': 186358588
}
```

It resolved after I restart. But Its expected to be this issue happen again in 4 days.

So Any recommendations are welcomed.